# Angular 11 - select first item in a dropdown list

Tags: angular, angular-forms

simple thing; I want the first item in a dropdown list (mat-select) to be automatically selected when page loads.
This code below is my best guess but doesn't work, I still see an empty text, I have to dropdown and select first item manually. Do you know why or how to fix it? Thank you.

```html
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Title</mat-label>
        <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedTitle" [(value)]="titleList[0].titleval">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let singleTitle of titleList" [value]="singleTitle.titleval">
                {{singleTitle.titletxt}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: I am not sure, but guessing this could work `<mat-option *ngFor="let singleTitle of titleList; let first=first" [value]="singleTitle.titleval [selected]="first">`

Comment: sorry Markus, it doesn't work for me, this was my first try as well but I used the index instead first. I don't know why angular doesn't let you do it or maybe it's the material library.

Comment: no it doesn't work on simple html select component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let angular do it for you

In your TS file e.g in your `ngOnInit()`

```
this.selectedTitle = this.titleList[0].titleval
```

and your html

```html
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Title</mat-label>
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedTitle">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let singleTitle of titleList" [value]="singleTitle.titleval">
            {{singleTitle.titletxt}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

angular will select the first item for you

Comment: perfect Kelvin, I like your approach because we can also have more control on what to select or check if it's available at all etc.